# Does Chinese music avoid counting in 4s?

Tags: meter

Many East Asian cultures consider the number 4 to be unlucky, because their words for that number are highly homophonic to the word for death.  Quite often you will see companies skipping the number 4 in their product numbers to avoid being unlucky and many buildings do not have a 4th floor (akin to how many Western buildings do not have a 13th).

When I listen to Chinese music, I hear groups of 4 beats, which seems funny given their attitude towards 4.  The literature I find considers their music to be "duple," a category that includes both 2/4 and 4/4 time in Western terminology. It occurred to me the other day that the groups of 4 might be in my head, as a Westerner, as I apply my own structure to their music.

Do Chinese composers and musicians count their music differently, perhaps counting in groups of 2 or 8 instead?

Comment: The same homophone exists in the Japanese language (since both words are derived from the Chinese words), so I wonder the same about traditional Japanese music now.

Comment: Possibly informative:  https://www.teachervision.com/china/resource/8575.html

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Thank you for the link.  I had come across it, but it certainly is the closest to a definitive answer I have identified so far.  It does suggest that counting was done in groups of 2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way of expressing meter in traditional Chinese music is in terms of *ban* and *yan* - 'beats' and 'eyes'. The 'ban' represents the main beat, or the pulse of the bar, while the 'yan' (eye) represents a weak beat. Some common meters were

- One ban followed by three yans : **ban** - yan - yan - yan - **ban** - yan - yan - yan
- Alternating : **ban** - yan - **ban** - yan
- Constant strong beat : **ban** - **ban** - **ban** - **ban**

You can probably see the similarity of the first one to a time signature involving the dreaded unlucky number you mentioned - but expressing it in this way, we've been able to avoid mentioning it!

refs:
[The Concise Garland Encyclopedia of World Music](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=73MO0eiQD_EC&pg=PA1093&lpg=PA1093&dq=chinese%20music%20ban%20yan%20beat&source=bl&ots=ywOBRfd7ZW&sig=PktwZl8qm0aeAz2ODKa9PJNrePM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VbwdVamlB4rzUJC8gIgL&ved=0CDIQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=chinese%20music%20ban%20yan%20beat&f=false)
[SOAS lesson on Chinese music](https://www.soas.ac.uk/music/schools/lessons-for-schools-1-china.html)
[World Musics in Context](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=i2vDlcIyVjUC&pg=PA362&lpg=PA362&dq=chinese%20beat%20ban%20eye%20yan&source=bl&ots=koDFxaTNXD&sig=sMjnw6by6ciWLvjZTKfqdEqB6AQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=D7sdVcXWNczoUqaqgcgG&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=chinese%20beat%20ban%20eye%20yan&f=false)

Of course if expressing your meter through western time signatures, you have to use the appropriate number, putting your superstition on one side. Superstitions are like that : they can't be too impractical. I'm sure most cars in China have four wheels!